# TypeORM: How to define nested data relationships?

Tags: sql, join, nested, typeorm

I am looking at using TypeORM for a new project (TypeScript + express).

How can I define a nested relationship?

Here's an example of the data structure:

```
Topic:
{
  applicationId: 2,
  name: 'test',
  recipients: [
    {
      id: 1,
      transports: [
        {
          id: 1,
          templateId: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          templateId: 1,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      transports: [
        {
          id: 1,
          templateId: 4,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  startTime: null,
}
```

A `Topic` can have 1 or more `Recipients`.  For each `Recipient`, there is 1 or more `Transports`.

Currently I am defining the relationship with a single join table:

```
CREATE TABLE topics_recipients_transports
(
  id          INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  topicId     INT NOT NULL REFERENCES topics,
  recipientId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES recipients,
  transportId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES transports,
  templateId  INT NOT NULL REFERENCES templates,
  config      NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX topics_recipients_transports_unique
  ON topics_recipients_transports (topicId, recipientId, transportId)
GO
```

As you can see, the relationship is one-to-many from `Topic -> Recipient -> Transport` but the relationship from `Transport -> Recipient` is dependent on the `Recipient -> Topic` association.

Comment: I have the same problem...

Answer (score 3):

Nested relationship can be defined as:

```
this.topicRepo.find({ relations: ["recipients", "recipients.transports"] });
```